# iptables rules applied multiple times

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, firewall, kvm-virtualization

I had a very simple set of iptables rules on a newly installed system:

```
$ sudo iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I load and save the rules using scripts in /etc/network/if- folders:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.downrules ]; then
   iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
fi
exit 0
```

After installing qemu-kvm my rules were adjusted (from what I read by libvirt), to make my virtual machines use the network - this is all fine.

However, every time I restart my host PC, rules get enriched by exactly the same set for qumu-kvm. So after couple of restarts this is how my rules look like:

```
$ cat /etc/iptables.rules 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:73]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:73]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:353]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8:353]
[1:40] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:506]
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[36:2484] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[6:1810] -A INPUT -j DROP
[0:0] -A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j DROP
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [10:466]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10:466]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:506]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [11:506]
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 24 09:53:26 2018
```

You can see a lot of them are just copied multiple times. If I don't clean this regularly it becomes really messy as you can imagine.

I don't want to paste another long console output, but when I do ***sudo iptables -vL*** I can see all these doubles applied.

Question is why does it happen and how to prevent this?

Comment: Don't use the old iptables scripts. Use a firewall tool such as ufw or firewalld. These work properly with the firewall rules added by libvirtd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accumulation of repeated rules is occurring because you save them at the end, and then re-load them in addition to the system added rules related to KVM.

I would suggest to change away from the `iptables-restore` `iptables-save` method to just a script to load your specific iptables rules on startup.